# Attempting to use Excel Function LinEst from Access using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am attempting to use the Excel LinEst Function from Access to derive Heat Rate curves for a given set of data. I have researched different methods to make the Excel functions available within Access but my code does not succeed.

I am getting the following error message when I attempt to test the process.

"1004: Unable to get the LinEst Property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Here is my code. Any ideas of what am I doing wrong? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
Function PolyForm(yVals As Variant, xVals As Variant, PolyPower As Integer)

    Dim XArr() As Variant
    Dim xl As Object
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    XArr = XArray(xVals, PolyPower)
    PolyForm = xl.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yVals, XArr, True, True)
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing

End Function

Function XArray(InArr, PolyPower)

    Dim XArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    ReDim XArr(1 To UBound(InArr), 1 To PolyPower)
    For i = 1 To UBound(XArr)
    XArr(i, 1) = InArr(i)
        For j = 1 To PolyPower
            XArr(i, j) = XArr(i, 1) ^ j
        Next j
    Next i
    XArray = XArr

End Function
```

Comment: are both `yVals` and `xVals` of the same bounds & size? I am not very familiar with `LinEst` functio but some simple tests on Worksheet seem to suggest that the function call will fail if the arrays are not the same size.

Comment: Also, I think that in order to use `LinEst` on a multi-dimensional array, you need to invoke it as an `ArrayFormula` . You might consider revising your question to include a minimal amount of example data which others can use to test/debug the code.

Comment: Both arrays are of the same size. I tested the VBA structure in Excel prior to incorporating it into Access. That is the reason for the XArray Function, to create the needed XArr structure since VBA does not support array mathematics; or so my research has indicated.

Comment: I'll repeat: *You might consider revising your question to include a minimal amount of example data which others can use to test/debug the code.* :)

Comment: You might further include the VBA code you used to test this in Excel. It's a courtesy here (and rather expected of you) to provide your tests so that others don't have to try and reinvent the wheel (as most are not inclined to do so, anyways!).

Comment: The `XArray` that you're passing to the function is not the same size as the `yVals`, at least not when I test it in Excel and I don't see any reason why the result would be different in Access.

Comment: Specifically, `xArray` becomes `Variant(1 to 5, 1 to 2)` while `yVals` is `Variant/Variant(1 to 5)`